# What part of this code do I need to change to open link in same page, same tab?

Tags: html

I'm using this code for a website and I need it to open the link in the same tab and page.

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <form name="blah_blah"> 
        <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;"> 
        <option value="" selected>Select Site</option> 
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option> 
        <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option> 
        <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option> 
        <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option> 
        </select> 
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)"> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use window.open, use location.href instead

```
onClick="location.href = ddmenu_name.value;"
```

Full code:

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <form name="blah_blah"> 
        <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;"> 
        <option value="" selected>Select Site</option> 
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option> 
        <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option> 
        <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option> 
        <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option> 
        </select> 
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="location.href = ddmenu_name.value;"> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: So I it should be this?  <html> <body> <form name="blah_blah"> <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;"> <option value="" selected>Select Site</option> <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option> <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option> <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option> <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option> </select> <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.href =ddmenu_name.value;"> </form> </body> </html>